# Losing 1 unit of token when adding liquidity to Uniswapv3

Tags: uniswapv3

Is it normal that 1 unit of token is lost when adding liquidity to Uniswap v3 ?
For example, I have been adding USDC 10 to the MATIC/USDC pool on Uniswap v3 (Polygon), below the current price (I chose a range of 0.1 to 0.2).
When a few minutes later, I remove 100% of the liquidity of my position, I am only getting back USDC 0.999999 (1 unit of USDC is missing).
Is this expected/normal ?

Comment: Yes it's normal. There's a lot of math in UniV3, so I can't pinpoint exactly where, but rounding down the divisions when returning tokens to the user is the norm.